# Free Pascal - Create an array of previously declared elements/objects

Tags: pascal, freepascal, lazarus

Using Lazarus - Free Pascal under Win7 64Bit, Laz Version 2.0.2 , fpc 3.0.4 , i would like to know if it is possible to create an array of previously declared checkboxes `TCheckBox` or `TEdit`, or whatever element i would like.

Using something like this does not compile:

```
var
  myarray: array[1..2] of TCheckBox = (CheckBox1, CheckBox2);  //CheckBox1 has been declared earlier as TCheckBox
```

While this one compiles ok

```
var
  myarray: array[1..2] of TCheckBox;
begin
  myarray[1]:= CheckBox1;
  myarray[2]:= CheckBox2;
```

If i had 50 CheckBoxes, i would like to avoid assigning all of them to `myarray` one by one under `begin`.

Is it possible `myarray` values to be given during variable declaration, in `var` section?

Comment: No, you can't add them in the `var` declaration. In Delpih, you could do it in a loop, using the form's `Components` collection with `FindComponent`. There is sample code in several questions here; you can probably find one with a search expressioni like `[delphi] control array`.If you can't use that approach in FreePascal, you're stuck with assigning them as you do in your second example.

Comment: The component reference values aren't known at compile time, they aren't constant. So, no.

Answer (score 3):

In the declaration section you can not use variables, only constants. However you can use [dynamic array constructor](https://wiki.freepascal.org/Dynamic_array#initializing):

```
type
    TCheckBoxArray = array of TCheckBox;
var
    myarray: TCheckBoxArray;
begin
    myarray := TCheckBoxArray.Create(CheckBox1, CheckBox2);
```

Comment: I wasn't sure FP supported that syntax. I haven't looked at it in ages. :-)